# How do I declare a class template that is placed after the main?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a template class that is stack. But I want to declare it before main. Can I do that? I know it will compile if you put the main after the template but is it possible to put the main first then the template?

```
#include <iostream>


//start declaration of template
template <class T>
class stack<T>;
//end declaration of template
int main() {

    stack<char> s(5);
    s.push('a');
    s.push('b');
    cout <<s.pop()<<endl;
    stack<double> s1(10);
    s1.push(3.2);
    s1.push(0.5);
    cout << s1.pop()<<endl;

    return 0;
}


template <class T>
class stack {
    T *s;
    int size; //How many elements I can stole.
    int top; //Where the index is available.

public: 

    stack(int sz) {
        size = sz;
        s = new T[sz];
        top=-1;
    }

    void push(T e);
    T pop() {

        return s[top--];
    }
};



template <class T>
void stack<T>::push(T e) {

        s[++top] = e;
    }
```

Error given:

```
1>.\classTemplPers.cpp(6) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>.\classTemplPers.cpp(6) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
```

For the record, doing this:

```
template <class T>
class stack;
```

doesn't work either. I see errors like this:

```
1>.\classTemplPers.cpp(10) : error C2079: 's' uses undefined class 'stack<T>'
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I was tasked to do that by my teacher.

Comment: @PatrykWertka That's a perfectly valid thing to do. Why wouldn't it ?

Comment: Becouse, besides exercises, thats pretty useless to know.

Comment: @PatrykWertka saying that class declarations are useless is a pretty bold statement :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for declaring a template is, as Quentin already pointed out:

```
template <class T>
class stack;
```

But it won't help you because:

> is it possible to put the main first then the template?

You could do that only if you don't use the template in `main`.

But you do use the template, so no, you can't do that. The template must be defined before it can be instantiated. However, you may leave the definitions of the member functions after `main` if you  wish.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. The syntax is :

```
template <class T>
class stack;
```

But as any class declaration, it won't suffice if your use of it needs the full definition. Instanciating the template and using its member functions is one such case, so you're out of luck this time.

Comment: If I do that it gives me this:

Comment: classTemplPers.cpp(10) : error C2079: 's' uses undefined class 'stack<T>'